# Java - Why use EnumMap when enum itself can be used as a map?

Tags: java, enums, enum-map

I've been reading up Java recently. So I have a enum below that acts as a map with key "JESSIE" and value "My favorite cat".

So why does anyone need to use EnumMap? Thanks

```
public enum Cat {
    JESSIE("My favorite cat");

    private String description;

    Cat(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you have a hundred different maps?  Do you want a hundred fields in there?

Comment: You could add a field to any class you are writing.

Answer (score 6):

The `enum` is the **key** in an `EnumMap`, and therefore those two things are completely different. You have no way of knowing all the kinds of things you may want to associate with your cats.

The `description` may be an inherent part of `Cat`, but you might want to associate cats with their servants, or where they (currently) live or what their preferred meal (currently) is.

```
EnumMap<Cat, Human> catsServant;
EnumMap<Cat, House> catsHome;
EnumMap<Cat, Meal> catsFood;
```

Since you don't need to modify `Cat` to associate it with another object, it makes it a lot easier to use, and your enum would become huge if you filled it with *all* possible things you might want to associate your cats with.

A second issue is that `enum`s are singletons, which means that if you were to put *mutable state* (strongly discouraged!) in your `Cat` by adding a `setDescription(String)` method, it will change that globally in your program. That may not matter for simple programs or a simple property like `description`, but it does matter when you have more complex code.

Now a more realistic example. The JDK `TimeUnit` enum has values such as `MINUTE`, and the creators couldn't have known of all the possible things that people might want to associate with them. However with an `EnumMap` I can provide a translation to my native language as follows:

```
EnumMap<TimeUnit, String> xlate = new EnumMap<>(TimeUnit.class);
xlate.put(TimeUnit.MINUTE, "Minuutti");
xlate.put(TimeUnit.SECOND, "Sekunti");
```

`TimeUnit` isn't my class, so I can't edit it to include those translations, and it would be the wrong place anyway.

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406636/why-use-enummap-instead-of-hashmap) is why is there a special `EnumMap`, since you can also use a normal map, such as `HashMap<Cat, Human>`.

Comment: The related question section is not much in the interest/scope of this question and is answered pretty clearly in the [other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406636/why-use-enummap-instead-of-hashmap).

Answer (score 3):

The primary reason behind this would be to design the classes in such a way that it holds the attributes that represent its entity and not which it would require a mapping with while querying.

As an example, consider another class `Human` as follows

```
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Human {
    String name;
}
```

Now you could have looked for a `Cat` to its owner mapping, but how much of a sense would it make to keep the entire `Human` object referenced for such a mapping? Despite the fact, that you could keep such a reference, what's helpful for the purpose of query ability is to keep such a reference in an additional data structure `EnumMap` in this case -

```
EnumMap<Cat, Human> enumMap = new EnumMap<>(Cat.class);
enumMap.put(Cat.JESSIE, new Human("naman"));
enumMap.put(Cat.LUCY, new Human("user"));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and explanation, just curious - are there differences between my design below vs. using a enummap which you just mentioned? do they both do the same thing? thanks again

```
public enum Cat {
    JESSIE(new Human("naman"));

    private Human human;

    Cat(Human human){
        this.human = human;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2606235 The main difference is the extensibility and the threshold that your solution would reach. For example, how many such mapping `Human`s can you keep in the `enum`, they could all have different roles?